# Initialize an array of type using protocol

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-protocols

I wish to return an array of any type that conforms to an `ArrayObject` protocol by initializing it using a `JSON` and a `init` function all types conforming to the `ArrayObject` protocol must have. The function below worked perfectly fine in `swift2` but since updating to `swift3` initializing no longer takes place and the for-loop is skipped after the first attempt. I've set multitudes of break points but still can't understand why this happens

```
//MARK: Array protocol returns an array of types by initlizaing using the json passed
public protocol ArrayObject {
  init(results: JSON)
}

extension ArrayObject {
  public static func initialize<T:ArrayObject>(json: JSON) -> [T] {
    var array = [T]()
    //For loop bails after the first attempt **
    for i in 0..<json.count{
      array.append(T.init(results: json[i]))
    }
    return array
  }
}


struct Example: ArrayObject{

  var name: String!

  init(results: JSON) {
    name = results["name"].string
  }
}

struct Testing{
 func testing(json: JSON){
    var exampleArray = [Example]()
    exampleArray = Example.initialize(json: json)
  }
}
```

Comment: did you check 2 things: 1. if the JSON actually has only one subitem   2. Seems like your are using SwiftyJSON, did you try alternatives and look to see if SwiftyJSON is working correctly.

Comment: I'm 100% positive the JSON is not the problem and the project is too big to remove swiftjson